# Is this a correct proof that the union of two denumerable sets is denumerable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

"Say that $A\approx \omega$ and $B\approx \omega$, then prove that $A\cup B\approx \omega$."

There must exist $h:A\to\omega$
  such that $h$
  is 1-1, and a similar function $g$
  must exist for $B$
 . Define $f:A\cup B\to\omega$
  by $f(x)=\begin{cases}
2\cdot h(x) & x\in A\\
2\cdot g(x)+1 & x\in B
\end{cases}$

Now $\mathcal{R}(f)=E\cup O$, where

$E=\{x:(x\in\omega)\land(\exists y)(y\in\omega)(x=2\cdot y)\}$
  and $O=\{x:(x\in\omega)\land(\exists y)(y\in E)(x=y+1)\}$ ,

and so $\mathcal{R}(f)=\omega$ by the division algorithm, and clearly as $E$
 and $O$
  are disjoint and $g$ and $h$ are 1-1, $f$
  is 1-1. 
So $A\cup B\approx\omega$
 .

QED

Is this correct? The Peano axioms and the properties of addition and multiplication have been proven for finite ordinals, so I'm assuming that the division algorithm should be provable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost right but you are forgetting a couple of things and making some things harder then you need to in my opinion.

One problem you will have is that the $f$ you define need not be a function. In particular it will be ill-defined if $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$.

There is a few ways to fix this, one of which Mark has already beat me to.

My tendency though would be not to try and create a bijection, as that can get quite painful (not in this particular case but in general size comparison cases), but instead to use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem.

Then you just need two injections both of which are quite easy.

$f:A\cup B\hookrightarrow\omega$ can be almost what you had $f(x)=\begin{cases}
2\cdot h(x) & x\in A\\
2\cdot g(x)+1 & x\in B\setminus A
\end{cases}$

Both being a function and injectivity comes pretty much for free then.

For the other direction you have to do even less work since $g^{-1}:\omega\hookrightarrow B$ can just be composed with the identity injection from $B$ into $A\cup B$ and you are done.

I would agree this is not particularly important here since the problem is so easy, but there's a fair number of places where it's much easier to find two injections then one bijection. Just try $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea but the map $f$ as written is ill-defined (unless $A$ and $B$ are disjoint).  If $\exists x : x \in A \cap B$ then by your definition of $f$, 
$f(x)$ is both even ($2h(x)$ and odd ($2g(x)+1$).

To fix your proof, try $f(x)=\begin{cases}
3\cdot h(x) & x\in A \cap \sim B \\
3\cdot g(x)+1 & x\in B \cap \sim A \\
3\cdot k(x)+2 & x\in A \cap  B 
\end{cases}$

Then the division algorithm tells you that for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, the remainder when dividing $n$ by $3$ is in $\{0,1,2\}$ which in turn shows that 
$f^{-1}(n)$ is in $A \cap \sim B$, $B \cap \sim A$,  or $A \cap  B$ and thus the map is injective in that direction and (by definition) injective in the other direction, hence it is bijective.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about any members of both. That's the way I would've amended the proof, so thanks

Comment: This implicitly assumes that $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$ and $A\cap B$ are all infinite. It doesn't produce a bijection if $A=B=\mathbb N$, nor if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.